# How to scrape actor names + additional information from linked detail page?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using `Pandas` and `BeautifulSoup` and I'm have to get data from this link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chernobyl_(miniseries)&direction=next&oldid=899952822

First I had to get the first three actors names (Jared Harris, Stellan Skarsgård and Paul Ritter). Our lecturer send us an answer for this and it's not working. His answer was:

```
r = requests.get(link)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
names = html_soup.find("", {"class": "mw-parser-output"})
names = names.find("ul")
names = names.find_all("a", limit=3)
```

But this is not working. I tried the other way and did this:

```
names = data.find_all("td", {"class": "infobox-data attendee"})
for name in names:
    rows = name.find_all("ul")
    for row in rows:
        actor_names = row.find_all("li")
        for actor_name in actor_names[:3]:
            a = actor_name.find_all("a")[0]
            actors = a.get_text()
            print(actors)
```

This is working, but now I have to get birthday date from webpages of this three actors.

How do I do that and is there any way how to get actors names as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of starring you could use `:-soup-contains()` to lookup the label in the infobox and get all `<a>` from its sibling `<td>`.

```
soup.select('.infobox-label:-soup-contains("Starring") + td a')[:3]
```

You could simply get the values of `href` attribute by `get('href)` and use it for a new request to scrape additional information like date of birth from the actors page.

```
BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://en.wikipedia.org{a.get("href")}').text).select_one('.infobox .bday').text
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chernobyl_(miniseries)&direction=next&oldid=899952822').text)

for a in soup.select('.infobox-label:-soup-contains("Starring") + td a')[:3]:
    print(a.text)
    print(BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://en.wikipedia.org{a.get("href")}').text).select_one('.infobox .bday').text)
```

###### Output

```
Jared Harris
1961-08-24
Stellan Skarsgård
1951-06-13
Paul Ritter
1966-12-20
```

To get it as list of dicts:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chernobyl_(miniseries)&direction=next&oldid=899952822').text)

data = []

for a in soup.select('.infobox-label:-soup-contains("Starring") + td a')[:3]:
    actor = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://en.wikipedia.org{a.get("href")}').text)

    data.append({
        'actor_name':a.text,
        'birthday':actor.select_one('.infobox .bday').text,
        'any_additional':'ifromation'
        })

data
```

###### Output

```
[{'actor_name': 'Jared Harris',
  'birthday': '1961-08-24',
  'any_additional': 'ifromation'},
 {'actor_name': 'Stellan Skarsgård',
  'birthday': '1951-06-13',
  'any_additional': 'ifromation'},
 {'actor_name': 'Paul Ritter',
  'birthday': '1966-12-20',
  'any_additional': 'ifromation'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you use css selectors - the name hides in the first `<a>` in each `<li>` in the `<ul>` which immediately follows the `<h3>`:

```
for actor in soup.select('h3 + ul li a:first-of-type')[:3]:
    print(actor.text)
```

Output:

```
Jared Harris
Stellan Skarsgård
Emily Watson
```

Note that the 3rd actor is Emily Watson, not Paul Ritter (he is the 4th).

To get these names as a list, try:

```
[actor.text for actor in soup.select('h3 + ul li a:first-of-type')[:3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4

link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chernobyl_(miniseries)&direction=next&oldid=899952822'
data = []
response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
names = soup.find('th', text='Starring').parent.find_all('a', limit=3)

for name in names:
    actor = name.text.strip()
    link2 = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + name['href']
    soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link2).content)
    bday = soup2.find('th', text='Born').parent.find('span', {'class': 'bday'}).text
    data.append({'Name': name.text, 'Birthday': pd.to_datetime(bday)})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                Name   Birthday
0       Jared Harris 1961-08-24
1  Stellan Skarsgård 1951-06-13
2        Paul Ritter 1966-12-20
```